# Scroll View inside Reactnative (expo) is not working

Tags: react-native, expo

Here is my Code snippet:

```
 return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFF", flex: 1 }}>
      <ScrollView>
        
        <Image
          source={require("../images/image.jpg")}
          style={{ width: "100%", height: "60%" }}
        />[![enter image description here][1]][1]

        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            alignItems: "center",
            marginHorizontal: 55,
            borderWidth: 2,
            marginTop: 40,
            paddingHorizontal: 10,
            paddingRight: 30,
            borderColor: "#00716F",
            borderRadius: 23,
            paddingVertical: 2,
          }}
        >
          <Icon name="mail" color="#00716F" size={24} />
          <TextInput
            style={{ height: 40, width: "100%", paddingLeft: 5 }}
            placeholder="Email"
            value={email}
            onChangeText={setEmail}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
          />
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            alignItems: "center",
            marginHorizontal: 55,
            borderWidth: 2,
            marginTop: 15,
            paddingHorizontal: 10,
            paddingRight: 30,
            borderColor: "#00716F",
            borderRadius: 23,
            paddingVertical: 2,
          }}
        >
          <Icon name="lock" color="#00716F" size={24} />
          <TextInput
            style={{ height: 40, width: "100%", paddingLeft: 5 }}
            placeholder="Password"
            secureTextEntry
            value={password}
            onChangeText={setPassword}
          />
        </View>
       
        
       
        
        
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => signin({ email, password })}>
          <View
            style={{
              marginHorizontal: 55,
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              marginTop: 30,
              backgroundColor: "#00716F",
              paddingVertical: 10,
              borderRadius: 23,
            }}
          >
            
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <NavLink routeName="Signin" text="New User ? Signup Here." />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
```

**I have tried everything I don't know why my scroll view is not working
I have multiple TextInput elements but only a few of them only get rendered on the screen and the rest got trim. please help**

[image: Output]

**here I am attaching the screenshot of the output
I am using react-native expo
is this any package problem**
help me

Comment: Isn't it scrolling? Code seems fine. Do you want it to scroll?

Comment: what's the problem? is the scroll view not scrolling?

Comment: Nope it is not scrolling
I want it to scroll

Comment: Yes scroll view is not scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved

There was a very small mistake
I gave an element the margin of -200
So it was not scrolling
After i removed that margin
It was working smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Try set ScrollView property contentContainerStyle as below

```jsx
    <ScrollView
      contentContainerStyle={{flex:0}}
    >
```

Comment: still the form is not getting scrolled :(

Comment: Here is an example https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/scrolling-text